# Best way to control library versions and sys.path for a Python command-line application

Tags: python

I want to build a distributable, self-contained Python command line application with locked-down library versions. In Ruby I can control the libraries of my command line application by:

- including a Gemfile
- having the user run `bundle install` after cloning my application repository
- inserting a few lines of bundler boilerplate at the top of the command-line entry point script, which configures Ruby's `$LOAD_PATH` to include only the gems specified in the Gemfile

What is the equivalent process for Python? I am aware of `virtualenv`, do I need to have the user create a virtual environment and remember to activate it? This seems overly difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This largely depends upon the audience.

For developers, a good idea is indeed
 - Include requirements.txt
 - pip install -r requirements.txt

For end users, I'd recommend one of the follow:

- [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)
- [py2app](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/)
- [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

From this other StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726207/what-are-the-python-equivalents-to-rubys-bundler-perls-carton), [pbundler](https://github.com/zeha/pbundler) may also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, doesn't this install the requirements globally though? This covers the first 2 parts, but what about setting up `sys.path` at runtime to point exactly to the versions of each library specified in requirements.txt?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, updated above. w/ pbundler and cxFreeze.