# ImportError: No module named pytesseract

Tags: python, linux

I was following this guide https://realpython.com/blog/python/setting-up-a-simple-ocr-server/ and got to the part where I run cli.py `python flask_server/cli.py` but I get

```
python cli.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pytesseract
ImportError: No module named pytesseract
```

How can I solve this ?

I also saw that I have multiple versions of python. I have linux-kali installed with the latest updates.

Something else: he runs the command like `python flask_server/cli.py`- where is that flask_server located ? I simply ran it like `python cli.py`(I was in some directory in which I created the file).

Comment: You must install [pytesseract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract/0.1). It's not part of the standard library.

Comment: I followed the tutorial up to that point so it should be installed

Comment: Did you run the line `pip install -r requirements.txt` ? This would install all the required packages from the `requirement.txt` file, as explained in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726207/what-are-the-python-equivalents-to-rubys-bundler-perls-carton).

Comment: You mentioned you have multiple versions of Python so I strongly suspect that your `cli.py` and your `pytesseract` are installed relative to two separate versions. Solution: install `pytesseract` under the version you're running your script with, or run script with version that has `pytesseract`.

Comment: I took a script to show me the installed module on the python that was running cli.py and I got back only ['xsser==1.6']

Comment: This worked `pip install pytesseract`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python `import` errors usually boils down to one of those three cases (whether is is modules you developed; or modules distributed as packages):

1. You did no install the required package. Googling `pytesseract`tells me its an [OCR](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract/0.1) that is distributed and installable using Python package manager tool `pip` by running `pip install pytesseract` in your favorite shell.
2. You did install the package, but is is not in your python path.
3. (Less often) You did install the package, and it is in your python path, but you used a name already in user by Python, and the two are conflicting.

In your case, I strongly think this is the first one. Case 2. and 3. can be assessed by calling `python -v your_script.py`as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332299/trace-python-imports).

Comment: I took a script to show me the installed module on the python that was running `cli.py` and I got back only ['xsser==1.6']

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar error. So I hope to help people with this kind of problems.

In my case,
I tried to run python code using pytesseract lib on Raspberry pi 3.

```
$ pip install pillow
$ pip install pytesseract
```

(followed by https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/)

---

and then, I made an example.py to test.

## example.py

```
try:

    import Image

except ImportError:

    from PIL import Image

from pytesseract import *

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('YOUR_IMAGE_PATH')))
```

---

and then, when I run this code, I got below error like you.
    ImportError: No module named pytesseract

---

After I saw the @Bertrand Caron's answer, I found a solution.
**My problem was package library path.**

I also have multiple versions of python, 2.7 and 3.5, like a writer.
When I run command `$python --version` on linux, the result is Python 2.7.13.

In my case, when I installed a pytesseract package, 
it was stored in **"/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pytesseract"**.

And When I ran `$python -v example.py`, I found **the referenced packages path** hadn't been same with **upper pytesseract package directory**.

cf.

*installed pytesseract path : /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pytesseract*

*actual referenced lib path, when running : /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/*

**So, I copied pytesseract, located in "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pytesseract" to "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/"**

Then, Solved!

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was running it in Jupyter so I used this command,

```
! pip install --user pytesseract
```

But I forgot to restart the kernal. **You need to restart the kernal after installing the pakcage**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. My solution is

```
$ pip3 install pytesseract
```

since I have python 2 and python 3 installed together.