# How to get a package to point to correct path in virtual env?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, virtualenv, tesseract

I am trying to install *pytesseract* in a virtual environment in Anaconda prompt. I have tried the following commands

```
conda create -y -n tesseract python=3.8
conda activate tesseract
conda install -c conda-forge pytesseract
```

After this I installed the tesseract OCR

```
conda install -c conda-forge tesseract
```

Next I added my virtual environment(*tesseract*) to Jupyter by typing:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=tesseract
```

After this I launch the *jupyter lab*

I tried the following code (from https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/how-to-install-pytesseract.html)

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\envs\tesseract\Library\bin\tesseract.exe'
```

The problem is that I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    import pytesseract
ImportError: No module named pytesseract
```

I have looked at the answer for a similar problem(https://stackoverflow.com/a/51530457/12164941). My question is that even though my jupyter notebook is running in my virtual environment and the *pytesseract* library is added and exist in *C:\Users\abc\anaconda3\envs\tesseract\Lib\site-packages* why do i still get the error?

However I no longer get the error if I copy the *pytesseract* package folder from  *C:\Users\abc\anaconda3\envs\tesseract\Lib\site-packages* to *C:\Users\abc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages*

Answer (score 0):

> if I copy the pytesseract package folder from C:\Users\abc\anaconda3\envs\tesseract\Lib\site-packages to C:\Users\abc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

You should refrain from doing so, even though it gives the answer in this case

Your jupyter notebook is still using the kernel from your base env. You can easily check this by running

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

You will need to select the correct kernel from your environment